# Html5 video element on iPad4 Safari

Tags: html, ipad, video, safari, html5-video

I'm trying to add video to page with html5 video container. It works good on pc's browsers, android chrome, but make blue area unavailable on iPad4 Safari.

```
<div class="b-video">
    <video poster="star.png" controls tabindex="0">
        <source id="mp4" src="videos/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source id="webm" src="videos/trailer.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source id="ogv" src="videos/trailer.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
</div>
```

[image: iPad4 Safari unavailable area]
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

iOS Safari's `<video>` element does not forward user interaction events (touch, click) if the native `controls` are enabled on it (which is your case).